# Add custom rule to indicative library

Tags: javascript, node.js

I was suggested to use this [Indicative](https://indicative.adonisjs.com/) package, so far so good but I was reading the docs and can't find a rule to check whether the variable is defined

`required` almost did the job but if the string or array is empty it will throw an error, which I want it to be okay

I tried this too

```
let rules{
    username:"string"
}
```

But if the `username` is `undefined` for some reason it doesn't throw an error even though the `username` property isn't there and it definitely isn't a `string`

If this rule does not exist I would want to edit the library and add it my self, but I'm beginning to learn JavaScript I don't know how to approach this